# button in razor collection, the controller can't see the button value

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got a razor view as such:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RemoveContact", "MyContacts"))
{ 
    <table>
        @foreach (MyProject.Models.MyContacts.ExistingContact ec in Model.ExistingContacts)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@ec.FirstName</td>
            <td>@ec.LastName</td>
            <td>@ec.Relationship</td>
            <td>@ec.Phone</td>
            <td>@ec.Email</td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" name="Delete" id="Delete" value="@ec.ContactGuid">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
            }
    </table>
}
```

Basically I have a list of contacts, and I want to put a button next to each one that allows them to delete. On the same page is a form that allows them to add a new contact (that works fine).

But in my controller, which gets called, **the string argument shows up as null**. I would expect it to be the button's value attribute (@ec.ContactGuid).

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RemoveContact(String contactGuid)
{
    return Redirect("/MyContacts/");
}
```

1) Is there a way to fix this?

2) Is there some better paradigm I'm totally missing? I'm a new MVC developer.

Comment: Your button's name is Delete, not contactGuid.

Comment: @WiktorZychla didn't even know that's the linkage between the button and the method argument, thanks man, works great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter name passed in has to match the name, so since your name is Delete:

```
<button type="submit" name="Delete" ..
```

Delete has to be the name of the parameter, not the value; in this case, doing the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RemoveContact(String Delete)
```

the variable Delete will have the value of `@ec.ContactGuid` on click.